# Simple query with function_score not working in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to Elasticsearch, this should be simple but I can't find the problem...

I would like the sort order to be a combination of the Elasticsearch  `'_score'` and the value of a given integer field `'note'`. So I tried to use a function score query, with `'field_value_factor'`, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "note"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the first lines of the result:

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 195574,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "app",
            "_type": "city",
            "_id": "1705",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "note": 89,
                "postcode": "04320",
                "names": [
                    {
                        "name": "Sausses"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "_index": "app",
            "_type": "city",
            "_id": "1712",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "note": 61,
                "postcode": "04330",
                "names": [
                    {
                        "name": "Blieux"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "_index": "app",
            "_type": "city",
            "_id": "1717",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "note": 253,
                "postcode": "04340",
                "names": [
                    {
                        "name": "Saint-Vincent-les-Forts"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

The `_score` is always 1, the value of `note` is not taken into account, and the results are not sorted the way I would like.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Version of Elasticsearch: 1.7.5

Comment: Can you tell how you're sending your query and which which client?

Comment: @Val : With the head plugin, un the "other requests" tab.

Comment: With method GET or POST?

Comment: @Val: Ok, I tried with POST, it just work! Thank you so much.

Comment: In the head plugin, GET will ignore the query in the body, you must use POST